# Metro Bundler and Expo need a cert, both get error unable to find valid certification path to requested target

Tags: android, react-native, ssl

> -Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
>
> -- Could not download kotlin-reflect.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.3.20)
>
> --- Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.20/kotlin-reflect-1.3.20.jar'.
>
> ---- Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-reflect/1.3.20/kotlin-reflect-1.3.20.jar'.
>
> ----- sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target
>
> -Could not download kotlin-stdlib.jar (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.3.20)
>
> -- Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.20/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.20.jar'.
>
> --- Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib/1.3.20/kotlin-stdlib-1.3.20.jar'.
>
> ---- sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed:
>   sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to
>   find valid certification path to requested target

I also got the error in Android studio but was able to fix it by jumping through several burning hoops with keytool and adding certs to Android studio security.

I can't find any documentation on adding certs for either of these tools.  The names of the tools means google is a bit lost on it, my google foo has failed.  I am currently investigating react native and keep hitting this certification roadblock.  I have the cert I need to use, just need to know what to do with it.

Thank you